# Transpose of a complex Matrix in MATLAB

Tags: complex-numbers, matlab

Lets say we have a **Complex Matrix**

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        a+ib & c+id \\
        e+if & g+ih &
        \end{matrix}
$$

MATLAB shows the transpose of this matrix as

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        a-ib & e-if \\
        c-id & g-ih &
        \end{matrix}
$$

But why do we do this? Why isn't it simply

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        a+ib & e+if \\
        c+id & g+ih &
        \end{matrix}
$$

There is **Conjugate Transpose** of a Matrix. What about **Simple Transpose**? Why doesn't it exist?

Comment: A' is conjugate transpose. A.' is just transpose.

Comment: For more clarity use the tranpose and ctranspose functions.

Comment: You might consider adding "in MATLAB" to the question title. :)

Comment: As to "why do we do this?": because in calculations with complex matrices, you pretty much always need the complex transpose instead of the simple transpose; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28104040/why-is-complex-conjugate-transpose-the-default-in-matlab

Comment: First result in google searching for "transpose matlab" ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the two MATLAB commands

$(i)$ B=A.' Gives simple transposed matrix (without complex conjugate)

$(ii)$ B=A' Gives conjugate transpose